# Form get targeted at website load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Since adding a contact form to my website, when I refresh the page it constantly scrolls the page to where the form is.
I don't know what could provoke this, so I came to ask.  I searched for similar issues but couldn't find any. 
Thanks for all.

Form from site:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Nom prénom" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="email@example.com" required="required" />
    <input type="phone" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="00.00.00.00.00" />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Bonjour,..." required="required"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" value="Envoyer!" id="submit-button" >Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

Corrected form :

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Nom prénom" required="required" />
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="email@example.com" required="required" />
    <input type="phone" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="00.00.00.00.00" />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Bonjour,..." required="required"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" value="Envoyer!" id="submit-button" >Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

When you copy an old form, be sure to properly read each line (my biggest error there). 

**There was an autofocus attribute** in my form and that's what caused the problem.

Comment: Please provide relevant code here.

Comment: show us the code you added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with the 'autofocus' attribute.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp

You should remove it from the following form like so:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Maamar Miloud" required="required" />
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="contact.maamar@gmail.com" required="required" />
    <input type="phone" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="06.15.73.0x.0x" />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Bonjour,..." required="required"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" value="Envoyer!" id="submit-button" >Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

Here's a fiddle showing an extreme example: http://jsfiddle.net/xefq9t0z/1/

It's much easier to help you when you provide snippets of code so we don't have to dig through your entire site!  You're very lucky that I'm very bored!

Comment: If you could edit your question so it includes the code from your form (basically what I have above), it would really help anyone who visits this question in the future.  I've seen people overlook the autofocus attribute before and it would be helpful to have a good question about it on this site.